# How to debug a background IDE that Jenkins starts as a SYSTEM user

Tags: debugging, windows-7, jenkins, background-process, ole-automation

We are successfully using the Jenkins CI server on Windows 7. It mainly does compiles using CodeWarrior. Using the Win32::OLE library in Perl to automate the IDE, I recently added a new Unit Test job that compiles then also starts the debugger, runs a test thread on target hardware, then stops. It works fine when I start it from a command line under my user name, however when Jenkins starts the same task the IDE consumes all the CPU and never ends. Under the Windows Task Manager I see the IDE running as a SYSTEM user. I suspect there's a new pop-up message I haven't accounted for in my OLE automation, but can't see it because it's a background task now.

Is there a tool or technique to help debug windows that Jenkins starts as a system user but aren't visible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run Jenkins not as a Windows service, and then you should see the IDE pop up on your desktop.

Comment: Thanks. After doing a little searching it looks like entering "java -jar jenkins.war" allows it to start under a different user properly. On Windows 7 simply starting "Jenkins.exe" as a different user does not work because there are compiled in assumptions about it being run as a service.